# Source safe compare old version to current version

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

How do you compare an old version of a source safe project to the current one.

I want to look at all the differences in the project since we went live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can think of to doing this is to go to the root directory and ask it to "show history" with the little "Recursive" box checked. That will show you all changes to your project ever. If you know the date or label you want to start at, you can put that in the "from" box to constrain the search a bit.

Then go get some coffee while VSS chews on its disk for several minutes...

Comment: Tried this 3 times and each time VSS crashe (I love VSS so much NOT). Had to go through each file..gonna take a while. Tanks SP

Comment: @Steven - Lol. Yeah, using VSS beats flipping burgers for a living...barely.

Answer (score 0):

I use VSS 8 so there is no little "Recursive" box to check, but "Show history" then select two different versions works.